# Wrapper class dll from XSD

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am pretty new to C#. Before posting this here, I searched the web and gone through many posts but couldn't get the exact answer.

I have a xsd and I need to create *wrapperclass.DLL file from this xsd.

I have tried using xsd.exe, but the command prompt window closes as soon as it is launched.

If there is some other way to achieve this, please provide your inputs. Working on Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: "I have tried using xsd.exe, but ..." - document this better, because most answers will use the command prompt. Did you open a separate cmd window?  The VS2010 developer one?

Comment: +1 to the previous comment. Launching xsd.exe directly is *probably* printing an error message saying that it doesn't know what to do because you've passed it no arguments, and immediately exiting. The right way to use command-line tools is to invoke them in the command prompt.

Comment: You should open the CMD-Window and navigate inside of it to the xsd.exe. If you just run the exe, the window will automatically close after XSD.exe has been closed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
Now that this is resolved, have another issue. The XSD I have has an extension. I followed all the instructions mentioned for extension in base xsd and executed the following command:
xsd.exe base.xsd /c. This command returned error "the element "from extension" is missing.
I did some google and used following command:
xsd.exe /c base.xsd extension.xsd. this command didn't give any error but the resulting cs file didn't have all the variables defined. Could you please explain the possible reason for this.